# Position absolute, window resize problem even after converting to percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //console.log($("#content").children().first());
  $("#content").append('<div id="slider"></div>');
  // initially reset
  var left = $("#content").children().first().position().left;
  var width = $("#content").children().first().width();
  $('#slider').css({
    'left': left,
    'width': width
  });

  var delay = 150,
    setTimeoutConst;
  $('.steps').hover(function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function() {
      var left = $(that).position().left;
      var width = $("#content").children().first().width();
      $('#slider').stop().animate({
        'left': left,
        'width': width
      }, 300);
    }, delay);
  }, function() {
    clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst);
  });

})
```

```css
#content {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 15px 2.5% 0px 2.5%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.steps {
  width: 20%;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

#slider {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content-wrap">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="steps" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
      <div class="steps" style="background-color:black"></div>
      <div class="steps" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
      <div class="steps" style="background-color: black;"></div>
      <div class="steps" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have created a slider div that slides when hovered over the div elements of class= "steps". The problem is when I resize the window the slider div is not adjusting its width. So I converted the width to percentage values. There are 5 div's (class="steps") inside a wrap, each with width=20%, along with the slider div inside the same wrap with width="20% (to match the width of steps div's). But the width of slider div is more than that of the steps div. 
What should I do, so that the slider div is same as the width of steps div and its adjusts its width when resizing the window?

Answer (score 2):

Use Flexbox to create rows or columns of elements. Set `display: flex` on the `#content` element to make it a *flex-container*. All the children inside the container will be considered as *flex-children*.

CSS Tricks has a [great guide on Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Be sure to check it out.

[Here is an explanation](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) why `display: inline-block` creates the whitespaces that you currently have.

You need to add some CSS rules to  make the `#slider` element resize. First of all make sure that parent element, or container, of the slider has `position: relative`. This positions every `absolute` positioned element in relation the the `relative` parent.

Now the `width: 20%` on the slider will be the same width on a `.step` element and makes the slider resize **without** using JavaScript. If it is a styling issue, it probably can (and should) be fixed with CSS, remember that.

Also use the `border-box` model to combine padding and width on an element. By default all elements have `box-sizing: content-box` which will add padding to the width. For example: `width: 100px` and `padding: 0 10px 0 10px` will make the element width `120px`.

Using `box-sizing: border-box` will not add the padding to the width (or height) and only adds padding to the inside of the element. [MDN has some awesome examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to show how it works.

Check out the updated example and let me know if it works.

---

### Edit

The issue with positioning on resize comes from the fixed valued position of the slider element. This value has to be recalculated to a percentage value based on the width of a single step.

You can do this by checking the index of the currently hovered upon element and multiply the index by the width of a single step. Now add the `'%'` string behind the number and you'll get values `'0%'` for the first index, `'20%'` for the second, `'40%'`, and so on.

Now the slider element will be in the correct position at any time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //console.log($("#content").children().first());
  $("#content").append('<div id="slider"></div>');

  var delay = 150,
    width = 20,
    setTimeoutConst;
  $('.steps').hover(function() {
    var $that = $(this),
      index = $that.index();
    setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function() {
      var left = index * width + '%';
      $('#slider').stop().animate({
        'left': left,
      }, 300);
    }, delay);
  }, function() {
    clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst);
  });

})
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#content-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 2.5% 0px 2.5%;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.steps {
  width: 20%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
}

#slider {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content-wrap">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="steps" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
      <div class="steps" style="background-color: black"></div>
      <div class="steps" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
      <div class="steps" style="background-color: black;"></div>
      <div class="steps" style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In this case also, the slider div is not adjusting the width when the window is resized.

Comment: I've updated the answer and added more explanation to what is happened and how you should approach it.

Comment: The width adjustment is fixed, but positioning is not!